# Count elements in array inside function

Tags: c

I know that similar question was asked but, I need some explanation:
There is a code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count_pieces(double *array){
    int i = 0;
    while(*(array + i)){  
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
int main()
{   
    int i;
    int n=1005;
    double r[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        *(r+i) = 100.0;
        printf("%f\n", *(r+i));
    }
    printf("\n----------------------\n");
    printf("N=%d",count_pieces(r)); 
    printf("\n----------------------\n");
    return 1;
}
```

count_pieces() was taken from [know-all.net](http://know-all.net) and was adapted for double. All works FINE. BUT! - when I comment line: `printf("%f\n", *(r+i));` It becomes work incomprehensible! Why? What's happening?

Comment: Your code has a very important problem, `double x; if (x == 0)` will most likely fail if `0` was not assigned explicitly to `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't count items in a `double` array, that technique is used for strings, because in c strings have a special last value `'\0'` which is basically `0`, hence it can be used as a truth value in a loop to help count characters or find the end of the string for any other purpose.

Specially in your case, all the elements are `100.0`, so why are you expecting `while (*(array + i))` to even start looping?

Also, you need to be clear about the syntax `*(array + i)` which is the same as `array[i]` and it's obvious which of the two is better.

In c you need to keep track about the number of elements of an array, if you want to "*though I don't like that*" you can use a struct

```
struct DoubleArray  
{
    double *data;
    size_t  size;
};
```

and then you could use functions to initialize, deinitialize, set/get values etc., for example

```
struct DoubleArray *new_double_array(size_t size)
{
    struct DoubleArray *array;
    array = malloc(sizeof(*array));
    if (array == NULL)
        return NULL;
    array->data = malloc(size * sizeof(double));
    if (array->data == NULL)
    {
        free(array);
        return NULL;
    }
    array->size = size;

    return array;
}
```

And then I'd recommend to make this struct **opaque**, i.e. to hide it's fields from the struct users, so that you can prevent misusing the fields.

Comment: Thanks 2 Iharob.
But the last thing which is haunted me:  printf("%f\n", *(r+i));
I am absolutely sure that with this line It works correct. I checked it out

Comment: Yes it must work if `i` is not too large to make a read out of bounds, but I strongly recommend `printf("%f\n", r[i]);` syntax, it's very clear what it means, whereas `printf("%f\n", *(r + i));` is harder to read.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand  about syntax. But I do not understand why printf has such an impact. Is it problem of GCC?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, in your code,

```
while(*(array + i)){
```

does not include any boundary check on the index `i`. So, it will create memory overrun and hence you'll face [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It does not have any effect for *commenting out `printf("%f\n", *(r+i));`*.

Also, there is a fundamental problem in your `count_pieces()` function. Without checking the input parameter `array` against NULL, you started to deference it. It can cause you serious trouble if the function is called with a NULL argument. You should put a check first.